# How to wrap an async package function?

Tags: javascript, node.js, asynchronous, promise, control-flow

I'm using the popular node library, [got](https://www.npmjs.com/package/got), to make simple `GET` requests to a JSON API.

I have a function that abstracts the request, like so:

```
function performRequest(url) {
  got(url, {
    json: true
  }).then(function (response) {
    return formatResponse(response.body);
  }).catch(function (error) {
    console.log(error.response.body);
  });
}
```

`formatResponse` is a simple synchronous method that modifies the JSON returned from the API.

**I would like to be able to call `performRequest` from another function and then use the return value (once resolved).  Currently, as `performRequest` is not recognized as an async method, my code is calling it and then proceeding immediately.**

```
function myBigFunction() {
  var url = composeUrl();
  var res = performRequest(url);

  doMoreStuffWithResponse(res);
}
```

I know that I need to utilize a `Promise`, however, I'm always unclear as to how to use a Promise in conjunction with a built-in library function that is already using a Promise (like in this case).

I'm also completely open to the possibility that I'm going about this all wrong.  In that case, I would appreciate some redirection.

Thank you for your time.

Comment: You can just tack another `then` onto the Promise returned from the library function. Promises (once resolved) are immutable. You can always call `then` on one to get the value out. And they're values, you can pass them around.

Comment: Thanks @JaredSmith — I'll try this out now and report back.

Comment: Don't forget to `return` the promise from `performRequest`

Comment: Thanks @Bergi — I've been having trouble implementing the above suggestions and I think this is the problem.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You'll always want to `return` a promise from your functions:

```
function performRequest(url) {
  return got(url, {
//^^^^^^
    json: true
  }).then(function(response) {
    return formatResponse(response.body);
  }, function(error) {
    throw new Error(error.response.body);
  });
}
```

With this, you can wait for the result in your big functions using another `then`:

```
function myBigFunction() {
  var url = composeUrl();
  var promise = performRequest(url);
  return promise.then(function(res) {
    return doMoreStuffWithResponse(res);
  });
}
```

or in short

```
function myBigFunction() {
  return performRequest(composeUrl()).then(doMoreStuffWithResponse);
}
```

so that you can call it like

```
myBigFunction().catch(function(error) {
  console.log(error.message);
});
```

Comment: Excellent.  Thank you very much.

Answer (score 3):

Understand what a Promise *is*. Its a *value*, you can treat it as such. In order to "read" the value, you pass a function to the Promise's `then` method. You don't need `myBigFunction`. Anything you want to run after the Promise resolves just needs to be passed to `then`:

```
var req = performRequest(composeURL());
req.then(doStuffWithResponse);
```

Now, I don't particularly care for this way although I do it fairly often. I prefer to have functions that *take* promises and invoke their `then` method:

```
var takesAPromise = function(p) {
  return p.then(/* does stuff */);
};
```

Note that it returns the Promise of the completed task. But what I like even better is this ES6 one-liner:

```
let wrap = f => p => p.then(val => f.call(null, val));
```

Now you can wrap arbitrary functions to take Promises as input and return them as output. If Promises were a monad, this would be their `bind` function. Making it work seamlessly with functions of arbitrary arity is left as an exercise to the reader.

Comment: Having functions that take promises (and don't do anything but wait for their result before doing anything) are awful. If you want to pass anything in, you have to create a promise first. And you cannot chain them to other promises: `a().then(b).then(takesAPromise).then(c)` doesn't work. (If you advocate for monads, `bind(c, bind(b, a()))` would still be ok but you shouldn't have "bound" functions)

Comment: @Bergi what I really like is using the decorator because you can have regular functions that you test with regular data, `compose` them all together, wrap the composed function, and then make one call to `then`.